# Twig with php __autoload() method?

Tags: php, twig, autoload

I have an issue with PHP (5.3.13) and Twig. I use Twig as standalone in a project, not with Symfony 2 so. I try to use the PHP __autoload() method to load my own classes, but classes are not loaded because of Twig : here my project :

```
myproject/
|_ classes/
|        |_ myclass1.class.php
|        |_ myclass2.class.php
|_ lib/
|    |_twig/
|         |_ lib/
|              |_ Twig/
|                    |_ Autoloader.php 
|_ index.php  
|_ autoload.php
```

index.php code:

```
require_once("lib/twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php");

Twig_Autoloader::register();
$loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem("templates");
$tpl = new \Twig_Environment($loader, array("cache"=>false));

try {
   $oTemplate = $tpl->loadTemplate($sId.".html");
} catch (Twig_Error_Loader $e) {
   $oTemplate = $tpl->loadTemplate("404.html");
}

require_once("autoload.php");

$object = new myclass1();
```

autoload.php code:

```
function __autoload($sClass) {
   include_once "classes/".$sClass.".class.php"; 
}
```

And the error is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'myclass1' not found in C:\Program Files\wamp\www\myproject\index.php'
```

How to solve it? I read that I should use namespaces but I didn't find how to.

Comment: I dont get it, you got Autoloader.php and autoload.php?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix `__autoload()` and [`spl_autoload_register`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.spl-autoload-register.php) (used by Twig). Either start using `spl_autoload_register()`, too, or follow the approach sketched in the PHP docs to re-enable its functionality in your own `__autoload()` implementation.